# Magento 2 error when try to set production mode on

Tags: magento2, error, deploy

I'm trying to put my Magento 2 installation into production mode, when I try it I get following error

```
Something went wrong while compiling generated code. See the error log for details.
Command returned non-zero exit code:
`/opt/alt/php56/usr/bin/php -f /home/magento2/public_html/bin/magento setup:di:compile`
#0 /home/magento2/public_html/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Model/Filesystem.php(245): Magento\Framework\App\Shell->execute('/opt/alt/php56/...')
#1 /home/magento2/public_html/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Model/Filesystem.php(143): Magento\Deploy\Model\Filesystem->compile(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#2 /home/magento2/public_html/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Model/Mode.php(83): Magento\Deploy\Model\Filesystem->regenerateStatic(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#3 /home/magento2/public_html/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Console/Command/SetModeCommand.php(100): Magento\Deploy\Model\Mode->enableProductionMode()
#4 /home/magento2/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php(257): Magento\Deploy\Console\Command\SetModeCommand->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#5 /home/magento2/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(874): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#6 /home/magento2/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(195): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Magento\Deploy\Console\Command\SetModeCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#7 /home/magento2/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php(96): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#8 /home/magento2/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(126): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#9 /home/magento2/public_html/bin/magento(23): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#10 {main}
```

But I was able to run `setup:di:compile` successfully, this error occures only when run `deploy:mode:set production`

please help me to understand this issue and resolve it.

Answer (score 4):

first, you can see file `var/log/system.log` if you found error Allowed memory size bla bla bla exhausted its mean you must change variable `memory_limit` in `php.ini` file, use larger value.

Comment: Yeah sometimes it loses connection with the redis server, so you can run `redis-cli flushall`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem earlier with a clean M 2.1 install (no products /DB) + plus the Porto theme.

To eliminate that it was the porto theme that caused the problems I made a new / fresh install of Magento 2.1 without any theme.

Then compilation worked*

One might conclude that it Porto theme was the problem. But There are on other factor.

On my second install I set memory limit to 2G when running the Setup Wizard (offical recommendation).

On my first install (the one with compilation problems) the memory limit where set to 768M. This might have caused a problem so therefor I not 100% that I can blame the Porto theme even if it´s the most likely cause.

BR

Answer (score 0):

You just try below the comment

php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production --skip-compilation

It will solve the error message